# Update password always returns "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

As I use Laravel passport, when I call the API update password, it also updates the password, but returns 401 Unauthorized.

I have tried this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'current_password' => 'required',
    'password' =>  ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->symbols()],
]);

$user = Auth::user();
$data = $request->all();
    
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->update();
    
$passwordHistory = PasswordHistory::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'password' => $user->password
]);
        
return response()->json([
    'message' => "Password changed successfully!",
    'status' => "success"
],200);
```